# Indexing only File Prperties

Tags: windows

I have recently transferred a few files from my external backup disk to my hard drive. I noticed that indexing services were running wild for a long time. I figured out that I had some really large pdf files that windows was trying to ndex.

What I found as a solution was to go to Control Panel->Indexing Options->File Types, locate the .pdf file type and change its filter to "Index properties only". I have later realized that I never in my life had the necessity to search generally a group of files for a specific term. So I went in all file types and changed their filter to "Index properties only".

Is there any way to change the filter to "Index properties only" for all file types without selecting each and changing it manually?